# Transformation from Normalized Low-Pass Filter to Denormalized High-Pass Filter

Tags: capacitor, filter, inductor, low-pass, high-pass-filter

I would like to ask a question about the a method (method number 2) to go from a normalized LPF to a HPF:
Note: normalized refers to frequency normalization for the mentioned filters.

1- One method allows to go from normalized LPF to denormalized HPF by using the transformation (refer to Figure below)
[image]

This then allows to get for example an inductor L' in the denormalized HPF by using the capacitor value C in the normalized LPF: L'= \$ \frac{1}{C\omega_{p}}\$

2- Another method allows to go from a normalized LPF to a HPF. However, I am not sure if it leads to a normalized or denormalized HPF. Here is the transformation (Figure below):

[image]

And an inductor L' in the HPF is obtained by L'= \$ \frac{1}{C\omega_{0}^{2}}\$ where C is the capacitor in the normalized LPF.

Would this L' represent the inductor in a normalized HPF or denormalized HPF in the case where we start from a normalized LPF?

Thank you

Comment: It does depend on L or C unless you choose that. it could depend on if R load is series or parallel load swapped with C for attenuation.

Comment: Just to make sure I got your point: Do you believe this means that using the second method, if the LPF is normalized, the HPF obtained would be as well?

Comment: Both methods are valid. The first one is normalized, the second isn't. You can easily verify this, numerically. Happy New Year.